# When I build for prod i get hashed files that when users refreshed we get 404s of the files not sure how to fix it

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, build

I am running angular app off a GCP storage 
when I run ng build --prod --base-href . --output-path ~/Dev/GCP/
it all works perfectly except...
If the user refreshes to get the new content, 404s on css and javascript 
I get the idea of if but how can I get it to understand the change without losing links cause of the hash.

I have tried turning off hash but that undoes the whole point of cache-busting right.

ng build --prod --base-href . --output-path ~/Dev/GCP/

user can refresh and not get 404 on files like js and css and some routes cuase of the js

Comment: which `HTTP server` you are using for production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a angular problem. Let me explain what happens:

1. The initial application is uploaded on GCP storage
2. The user hits the url and get the index.html base page
3. You redeploy with new hashes (cache busting)
4. The user hits the url and get the cached index.html base page from step 2 from the browser. This points to the old js and css files, which don't exist anymore.

To verify the above scenario (and if you are not going from CDN, which will need edges to be refreshed), when you hit 4 try to do it with force refresh (like ctrl+F5).

If you validate this, then you'll need to check GCP storage on how to apply no-cache header on your index.html

Comment: Thank you for replying, i been so busy i forgot about this and was about to re-ask without knowing, your 100% on the money! thnak you I also changed my base href from ./ to full url and things are cooking on gas. sorry my response was delayed